# como add classe em um elemento específico input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma página com muitos inputs.

```
<form action="">

<div class="row">
<label for="texto">texto</label>
    <input type="text" class="nome">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="texto">password</label>
    <input type="password" class="email">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
</div>
</form>
```

O CSS é mais ou menos assim...

```
<style>
form{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
    .row{
        background-color: #999;

    }
    label{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #099;
        display: block;
    }
    input.nome,
    input.email{
        height: 26px;
        width: 100%;
        border:none;
    }
    .repositorio{
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
.efeito{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transition:.5s;
}

.efeito.efeitoStart{
    left: 0; right: 0; 
}
</style>
```

e o jquery:

```
$( ".nome" ).focusin( function () {
$('.efeito').addClass("efeitoStart");
});
$( ".nome" ).focusout( function () {
$('.efeito').removeClass("efeitoStart");
});
```

Obviamente que isto funciona, mas aplica o efeito em todos os inputs, já que a classe que recebe o efeito é a mesma, seja para qualquer input.

Eu poderia aplicar uma ID para cada input, mas como o sistema contém muitos elementos, acredito que não seria legal um arquivo JS grande.

Como eu poderia aplicar a classe efeito apenas no span do input clicado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é dessa maneira que você queria, mas trocando o seletor que você tem quando aplica a classe, funciona, olha:

```js
$( "input" ).focusin( function () {
 $(this).next().find('.efeito').addClass("efeitoStart");
});
$( "input" ).focusout( function () {
 $(this).next().find('.efeito').removeClass("efeitoStart");
});
```

```css
form{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
    .row{
        background-color: #999;

    }
    label{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #099;
        display: block;
    }
    input.nome,
    input.email{
        height: 26px;
        width: 100%;
        border:none;
    }
    .repositorio{
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
.efeito{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transition:.5s;
}

.efeito.efeitoStart{
    left: 0; right: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">

<div class="row">
<label for="texto">texto</label>
    <input type="text" class="nome">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="texto">password</label>
    <input type="password" class="email">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
</div>
</form>
```

Vale lembrar que ficou muito específico. Se você trocar a estrutura daqueles `span's` ali, não vai mais funcionar

Comment: Valeu mesmo Artur... Já testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente... Muito Obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

Também é possível aplicar este efeito com CSS puro utilizando o seletor `:focus`[(saiba mais)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp), exemplo:

```css
form{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 200px auto;
}
.row{
  background-color: #999;
}
label{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #099;
  display: block;
}
input.nome,
input.email{
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
}

.repositorio{
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

input:focus ~ span.repositorio .efeito{
   left: 0; right: 0; 
 }

.efeito{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transition:.5s;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="texto">texto</label>
    <input type="text" class="nome">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="texto">password</label>
    <input type="password" class="email">
    <span class="repositorio"><span class="efeito"></span></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente também... Valeu!!!